# SessionID in QueryString

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a page that has some hidden panels on it and when you click the upload button it uploads the content and then shows the hidden panel on postback. But I need to add a sessionid to the QueryString, as such "Default.aspx?&SessionID=" + SessionId". But I don't want to use Response.Redirect or Server.Transfer because it reloads the page and makes the panel hidden. Is there a way to add this to the QueryString without using Response.Redirect or Server.Transfer?

Just to make it clear. I have a PostBack on the button click. I just dont want a Response.Redirect or Server.Transfer.

Thanks!

Comment: I get you want to put the sessionid in the querystring but what do you want to do with the session id?  Are you creating a link for the user based on the sessionid or do you want it to show in the querystring for the user to copy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in order to prevent data from being posted I believe that this would be the only way that you have to do it..
for example

```
Session["SessionId"] = coll.Get("SessionId").ToString();//or what ever value your trying to assign from a variable.

Response.Redirect(Request.Url.ToString()); // reload the page.
```

---

**Edit:**
Sorry about that that's a NameValueCollection "COLL" lower case coll not col1

```
NameValueCollection coll = (NameValueCollection) Request.Form;
```

Comment: Thanks! whats the col1 suppose to be. Also I have a PostBack when the upload button is clicked it postback I just cant have a Response.Redirect or Server Transfer.